# Getting Bad request at the time of submitting data using retrofit

Tags: java, android, api, retrofit, bad-request

[image]When I am posting data on to my server I am getting error code 400 , Bad request but the scenario is the data is getting posted but  my response.body() is fetching null data and showing the message of a bad request .
I am posting the signup class and the interface .

Signup.java

```
      OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
        httpClient.networkInterceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public com.squareup.okhttp.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                com.squareup.okhttp.Request request = chain.request().newBuilder()
                        .addHeader("X-Parse-Application-Id", "D3E7oCNNNI0dkv9GYmqZGw0h0GVnbCmJ65JLj7di")
                        .addHeader("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", "hO89YU3OETgnL8Xlnvb6y8ov8Tv6jw52SORxNkxl")
                        .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                        .build();
                return chain.proceed(request);
            }
        });

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://api.parse.com")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(httpClient)
                .build();
        signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                {
                    if (e5.getText().toString().length() < 8 && e5.getText().toString().length()!=0 )
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "password should be of minimum 8 characters", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
                {
                    if (e1.getText().toString().length() == 0 ||
                            e2.getText().toString().length() == 0 ||
                            e4.getText().toString().length() == 0 ||
                            e5.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Some fields are left empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        progress = ProgressDialog.show(signup.this, "Signing up",
                                "Please wait", true);
                        String s1 = e1.getText().toString();
                        String s2 = e2.getText().toString();
                       int countrycode=new Integer(OTP_Activity.t).intValue();
                        Long phonenumber=new Long(Long.parseLong(OTP_Activity.phnnum));
                        final String s3 = s1.concat(s2);
                        signupapi thisapi = retrofit.create(signupapi.class);
                        HashMap params = new HashMap();
                        params.put("username", OTP_Activity.phone);
                        params.put("fullName", s3);
                        params.put("password", e5.getText().toString());
                        params.put("email", e4.getText().toString());
                        params.put("firstName", s1);
                        params.put("lastName", s2);
                        params.put("countryCode", countrycode);
                        params.put("phoneNumber", phonenumber);
                        Call<Signupmodel> call = thisapi.postData(params);
                        Log.d("full name", s3);
                        Log.d("phone", OTP_Activity.phone);
                        Log.d("e5", e5.getText().toString());
                        Log.d("e4", e4.getText().toString());
                        Log.d("firstName",s1);
                        Log.d("lastName", s2);
                        Log.d("countryCode", String.valueOf(countrycode));
                        Log.d("PHoneNumber", String.valueOf(phonenumber));
                        // as now we have information in string. Lets stored them with the help of editor


                        call.enqueue(new Callback<Signupmodel>() {


                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(Response<Signupmodel> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                                if (response.body() != null) {
                                    progress.dismiss();
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(signup.this, Bottom_Tabs_Activity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                } else {




                               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response.message(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                                }

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                                progress.dismiss();

                                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }

                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Signup_Interface

```
package com.example.vikrant.safeshelter.Login;

import java.util.HashMap;

import retrofit.Call;
import retrofit.http.Body;
import retrofit.http.POST;






public interface signupapi
{

    @POST("/1/classes/_User")
    Call<Signupmodel> postData(@Body HashMap hm);
}
```

Comment: tried `String` instead of `HashMap` ? then change your `String` object to `json` on your `RestController` Method.

Comment: No I didn't , as this have to be done by using hashmap , handling all post requests  using hashmap and get requests using strings. @VikrantKashyap

Comment: I have just suggest you to  tryand debug your code to track is your data received or not ? and response accordingly in comments. Please post your `StackTrace` Too

Comment: added @VikrantKashyap

Comment: after replacing `hashmap` to `String ` Still you got the error ?? @vikrantSingh

Comment: yes , no difference @VikrantKashyap

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109562/discussion-between-vikrant-kashyap-and-vikrant-singh).